# How to show precisely that the conditional definition of validity is equivalent to the standard semantic definition.

Tags: logic, soft-question

My favorite definition of validity is :

A reasoning from premises P1, P2, P3...Pn to conclusion C is valid iff the corresponding material conditional : (P1&P2&P3...&Pn) --> C  is valid ( in other words, iff the conjunction of the premises logically imply the conclusion).

I'm looking for a rigorous proof of the fact that this definition is equivalent to the standard one :

a reasoning from a set of premises Gamma to a conclusion C is valid iff in all interpretation making all the members of Gamma true, the conclusion C is also true.

My question amounts, it seems to me, to  : *"how to show that the " logical consequence" relation is identical to the " logical implication" relation?"* ( I said " identical" but maybe I should have said " is the converse of").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider that the "standard" definition allows that the set $\Gamma$ is an infinite set of sentences, while a formula is a finite string: this mean that we cannot have a *conditional* with an infinite number of antecedents.

In addition, you have to consider that the first definition holds only if the logical language has the *conditional* connective (this is not mandatory) and if the conditional is defined truth-functionally, like in classical logic.

Having said that, consider for simplicity a set $\Gamma = \{ \alpha \}$.

Assume that we have $\alpha \vDash \varphi$ and assume - for contradiciton - that $\alpha \to \varphi$ is not *valid*.

This means that there is an interpretation $\mathscr I$ such that $\mathscr \nvDash \alpha \to \varphi$, i.e. such that $\mathscr \vDash \alpha$ and $\mathscr \nvDash \varphi$.

But this contradicts the assumption that $\alpha \vDash \varphi$.

Similar for the other direction.